# Tensorflow finfo (numeric limits)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

How do I access something like `numpy.finfo` (Or `torch.finfo`) in the tensorflow Python API? I want to look up things like the smallest increment or largest finite value of the given type (for example `tf.float32`). Some attributes are accessible directly;

```
tf.float32.max
>> -3.4028235e+38
tf.float32.min
>> -3.4028235e+38
```

But how about `epsilon`, `infinity` or similar?

I would expect a straightforward interface to c++ `std::numeric_limits`, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/epsilon

Answer (score 2):

You can always check this via PyTorch. Should be the same as in TF.

```
import torch
print(torch.finfo(torch.float16).eps) #0.0009765625
print(torch.finfo(torch.float32).eps) #1.1920928955078125e-07
print(torch.finfo(torch.float64).eps) #2.220446049250313e-16
print(torch.finfo(torch.double).eps)  #2.220446049250313e-16
```

Else this will be [keras epsilon](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/5a7a789ee9766b6a594bd4be8b9edb34e71d6500/keras/backend/common.py#L9) way:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.backend.epsilon() #1e-07
```

There is also `set_epsilon()` you can play with.