# How to "denormalize" a pytorch tensor?

Tags: python, regression, pytorch, normalization

I would like to normalize the labels for my neural network but also be able to reverse the normalization process, so that I can scale my prediction outputs back to the original size.

My labels are of the form:

```
[[ 2.25, 2345123.23],
 [ 1.13, 234565.11],
 ...
 [0.12, 990232.98]]
```

Now I would like to normalize each column such that the values range from 0 to 1.

I found that pytorch has the torch.nn.functional.normalize function which allows me to normalize along a specific dimension using whichever p-norm I desire.

Is there an existing inverse function that allows me to scale my normalized values?

Currently, I am using a custom function that performs feature scaling as follows which scales both columns together, however, I wanted to make sure I am not creating a function that already exists in the torch library before rewriting it.

```py
 A = lbl_min
 B = lbl_max
 a = lower_bound
 b = upper_bound
 self.labels = a*np.ones(shape) + (self.labels - A*np.ones(shape))*(b-a)/(B-A)
```

Additional information:
I am using a regression model to output continuous real world values. I need to "denormalize" my predictions in order to validate them against the true values. Also, if I were to use my model in a practical application, I would need my output back in its original units.

- My neural network predicts multiple values at once that are in very different ranges.
- The two values have different distributions but can be predicted from the same input.
- My input is an image into two CNN layers that then are fed into two fully connected layers

Comment: apparently, there is no framework based solution on this. look here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/simple-way-to-inverse-normalize-a-batch-of-input-variable/12385

Answer (score -1):

This is a trick question right.
It has **no sense to denormalize** your values.

Why? Because once you normalize them, the neural net should learn to create the predictions based on your normalized values.

So you are safe.

BTW, you will typically use mean and std of your data to normalize.

---

In case of the regression problems it is the same. At least the architectures I created so far. For instance: Create the model M1 to learn sum `+` operation.
You provide pair of values `a,b` and you set the sum `c` as prediction.

In case you train another model M2 with `a/10, b/10` and you again provide the `c` as prediction, this means you normalize the input.

All you have to do in the inference phase is to **normalize** your inputs (divide by 10) and you get the correct output.

[image]

Comment: This is not entirely true. For regression problems, rolling back the normalization of the target values is essential to obtain accurate predictions.

Comment: @prosti My case is exactly what norok2 pointed out. I have a regression problem and need to "denormalize"  my prediction afterwards. I will clarify this in my question.

Comment: @norok2 I created some experiment recently where I always used normalization of the inputs and never actually messed with the target, maybe this way of doing things can help avgjoe.

Comment: @avgJoe, thanks I actually believe you can try to leave the target intact, and only deal with the inputs in both training and inference phase of your work.

Comment: @prosti that is correct, if you do not normalize the target, but this is something I would generally avoid. For example, if your target values are in the order of the tolerance of your optimization you will observe funny result. Try your example with a `10e-20` factor and you will see.

Comment: @prosti I have tried predicting the raw values before and it does learn. However, I have experienced issues when using the regression to predict multiple values at the same time, especially when the values to be predicted are orders of magnitude apart. Hence, my goal was to normalize the values or at least scale the values to be in the same range, and then denormalize them when using the regression model in the real world. Regarding normalizing the inputs and not the labels. I am using a gray-scale image as input and hence haven't worried too much about normalization.

Comment: @avgJoe, even for the gray scaled images you may do normalize. The trick is what ever values you used for your training you should use them for the inference as well.

Comment: Regarding the *order of the magnitude* problem, say your targets are in range `[1e20, 5e20]`, I would then take the targets from the range [1,5]. After that I will know I should multiply my predictions with `1e20`. Have in mind there are [limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047155/tensorflow-finfo-numeric-limits/57922429#57922429) in PyTorch. If your target is from `[1e-10,1e10]`, then I surrender.

Comment: @Prosti Regarding using the same input scale for both training and inference, I concur and this is also what I do. Regarding the magnitudes: I am predicting multiple values at once. E.g. output_1 is in range 0.005 - 0.05, output_2 is in range 33000-550000. The distributions of output 1 and output 2 differ. So, it is a tricky problem to predict them in the same model without compromising performance. For example, in order to fix the exponential distribution of one of my values, I can take the log of those values and then reverse that after training. (Thank you for your patience and advice.)

Comment: The obvious choice would be to normalize or scale both values separately and then reverse the scaling and normalizing afterwards. If it is true that there is no built in function to that, then my question is answered. What scaling/normalizing method to implement is then a matter of experimentation on my end.

Comment: One solution would be to create two separate models and use the bigger batch sizes. If this is real time computation such as video analysis you find some pro GPU. These models would be for output_1 and output_2. You may also create one big model containing these two and PyTorch `forward` can decide where the data should go. Move the big model on CUDA and pack the inputs smart possible a tuple of batches one for model1 and one for model 2.